# How to I set firebase to not place my posts under a token?

Tags: jquery, ajax, get, firebase

I was able to post data to firebase by using JSON#strinfify, but Firebase places my data under a token -KDVHem-Y7U7Ku1svisk. Is there anyway I can get it to just place it in my 'users' property directly, like my 'jane' item?

//ajax request

```
    $.ajax({
      url: 'https://jleiphonebook.firebaseio.com/users.json',
      type: "POST",
      data: JSON.stringify(param),
      success: function (hey) {
        debugger
        alert(hey);
      }
    });
```

//Firebase data

```
users
 -KDVHem-Y7U7Ku1svisk
 firstName: 
"John"

 firstName: 
"jane"
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can, by calling using the `PUT` method rather than `POST`. Take a look at the Firebase documentation: https://www.firebase.com/docs/rest/api/#section-put

Firebase is just making sure it has a unique ID in your `users` list: if you're PUTing the data directly, you probably want to make sure that it has an ID you're choosing. For example: `https://jleiphonebook.firebaseio.com/users/jane.json`.

Firebase is really a big tree, so what you are getting is

```
users
  -> -KDVHem-Y7U7Ku1svisk
    -> { firstName: "john" }
  -> -KDVHem-hjhjlblbjl
    -> { firstName: "jane" }
```

If you `PUT` straight to users you'd get:

```
users
  -> { firstName: "jane" }
```

John would have been overwritten! If you specify the name you want though, you can have:

```
users
  -> john
    -> { firstName: "john" }
  -> jane
    -> { firstName: "jane" }
```